# creating application endpoint for MS BOT with skype for business and local exchange

Tags: powershell, botframework, exchange-server, skype-for-business

I can create application endpoint to the bot with New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint without any issues.
The problem is that we use skype for business (office365) and local exchange no hybrid connection yet I am not able to sync local AD account with the Azure ad account.

created the bot with name@ourdomoin.xx it creates the account in azure without any issues I can chat with it in skype.
the bot also needs to be able to respond to mails, i create an account in our local AD with the same UPN and try to sync it, but there seams to be some conflict instead it creates a new account in azure ad.

I want to be able to create the application endpoint to the bot, then sync my local AD account with the account created to be able to respond and recieve mail.

Answer (score 0):

A bot does not need an actual AD account to be able to run (there will be an AzureAD app registration though). But you will likely want a dedicated Office365 account to be the dedicated account for the bot email. How it typically works is that you create a bot, then *connect* it to an email **channel**. The naming of the bot does not (need to) have anything to do with the connecting it to the email channel. Find more information here on connecting your bot to the email channel:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-4.0